# WPF change notification of user control inside item template not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm trying to bind each view model in an `ObservableCollection<FilterControlViewmodel>` as `DataContext` to a user control `FilterControl` in an `ItemsControl`.

The binding itself works fine. `"InitialFilterName"` is displayed correctly from `FilterControlViewmodel.FilterName` but any updates on the property are not notified to the UI.

Also adding elements to `ObservableCollection<FilterControlViewmodel>` is working find and adding additional user controls. But again the values inside the `FilterControlViewmodel` are not updated to the UI.

Any hint on where the notification is missing is appreciated. Thanks.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
   <local:MainWindowViewmodel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<Grid>
   <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilterViewmodel.FilterControls}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <filter:FilterControl DataContext="{Binding}"></filter:FilterControl>
          </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

**FilterControl.xaml**

```xml
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:FilterControlViewmodel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid>
   <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding FilterName}"></Label>
   <ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding FilterValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding FilterValueSelected}"></ComboBox>
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Content="X" Command="{Binding ResetFilterCommand}"></Button>
</Grid>
```

**MainWindowViewmodel.cs**

```cs
public class MainWindowViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public FilterViewmodel FilterViewmodel
        {
            get => _filterViewmodel;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _filterViewmodel)) return;
                _filterViewmodel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

**FilterViewmodel.cs**

```cs
public class FilterViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ObservableCollection<FilterControlViewmodel> FilterControls
        {
            get => return _filterControls;
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _filterControls)) return;
                _filterControls = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

**FilterControlViewmodel.cs**

```cs
public class FilterControlViewmodel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   private string _filterName = "InitialFilterName";
   public string FilterName
   {
      get => _filterName;
      set
      {
         if (value == _filterName) return;
         _filterName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
   }
```

Comment: Unless you override equals, comparison of objects is just on their type. Remove the if checks in your setters.

Comment: @Andy Isn't object.equals (since not overridden) identical to reference equals in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the following markup as it creates another instance of `FilterControlViewmodel`:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:FilterControlViewmodel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The `FilterControl` will then inherit its `DataContext` from the current item (`FilterControlViewmodel`) in the `ItemsControl` without you having to set the `DataContext` property explicitly:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilterViewmodel.FilterControls}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <filter:FilterControl/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: That did the trick. Actually two instances don't make much sense ;) Thanks.